# Firefox Private browsing on separate window

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to open private browsing in separate window without closing existing tabs ?

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never:

This feature has been introduced in Firefox 20.

Read more [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info).